# How to let user delete images by clicking on a button on top of it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, bulk

I have found a suitable way to let user bulk upload images

- http://www.plupload.com/index.php

After upload the images, the next step is to let user delete them when they come back next time or even immediately after upload.

I'd like to create a film strip of images (scroll-able) so the user can press the delete button on top of each image to remove it. Perhaps even better, let user select the checkboxes on top of the images and then press a Delete button nearby to remove them all.

Is there an existing component to do that like how Plupload does upload so well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can virtually remove those images form screen using jQuery, pretending as the images are deleted. But, in order to permanently delete them you have to use some server side code as javaScript can't modify any server side or client side file.